# A change of assumption of the normal family in proving Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In the process of proving Riemann mapping theorem by normal family, Stein supposes $\mathcal{F}=\{f:\Omega\rightarrow D| f \text{ is holomorphism, injective and }f(0)=0\}$ , then he shows the function that maximizes $|f'（0）|$ is still in $\mathcal{F}$, finally, by square root trick he finds a contradicion.

My question is: if I suppose the normal family only to be $\mathcal{F}=\{f:\Omega\rightarrow D| f \text{ is holomorphism}\}$, I know the funcion $f_0$ that maximizes $|f'(0)|$ is still in $\mathcal{F}$, how can I prove $f_0$ is again injective and $f_0(0)=0$.

This quesion actually is the exercise 10.5 in Marshall's Complex Analysis.

Comment: should it say "biholomorphism" instead of "holomorphism"?

Comment: Yes, I just asked injective for surjective can be deduced by the same process of the original proof, but what I truly want $f_0$ to be is biholomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{D}\to \Omega$ be a conformal map such that $\varphi(0)=0$, and $g:=f_0\circ\varphi:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$. Suppose that $f_0$ is not injective: then $g(z)\neq z$, and thus $|g'(0)|<1$ (from Schwarz's lemma), which implies $|f_0'(0)||\varphi'(0)|<1$, and thus $|f_0'(0)|<\frac{1}{|\varphi'(0)|}=|(\varphi^{-1})'(0)|$. Since $\varphi^{-1}\in \mathcal{F}$, we obtain a contradiction.